# Adding multiple products to cart in Spree store (Rails 4.2.5.2 / Spree 3.1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I'm trying to create a section on the Product show page that will display 3 products, with checkboxes beneath them, and a button to add the selected ones to the cart. As I have it now, only the last item is being added to the cart, I believe because the multiple variables with the same name are being used, and only the last one is selected (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288123/spree-ruby-on-rails-add-to-cart-multiple-variants-of-the-same-product)).

The answer linked above is for Spree 2.0.4, and I'm using 3.1.0, so I can't quite use the answer as discussed there.

I have looked into the Spree API, as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941045/adding-multiple-products-to-spree-cart-with-single-click) question (and also using Rails 4 and Spree 3, so much closer to the versions I need). But there is no answer, just a comment saying "use the api" and no discussion on how to do so.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202564/spree-how-to-add-multiple-products-to-cart) suggested using Spree Promotions, but I don't think that's what I need.

(This [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353161/spree-adding-multiple-variants-to-cart-on-the-same-page) answer was using Rails 3.2, and I couldn't find the model `order_populate` they referenced.)

Here is my code:

```
<%= form_for :order, url: populate_orders_path do |f| %>
  <!-- placeholder; select actual products later -->
  <% Spree::Product.all.take(3).each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <% if product.can_supply? %>
      <%= render partial: 'spree/products/product', locals: { product: product } %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "variant_id", product.master.can_supply? ? product.master.id : product.variants.find(&:can_supply?).id %>
      <!-- placeholder; replace with checkbox after hardcoded quantity working -->
      <%= hidden_field_tag :quantity, 1 %>
      <%#= check_box "quantity", product.master.id, { class: "similar-product-checkbox" } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <%= button_tag class: 'btn btn-success primary-cta', id: 'add-pairings-to-cart-button', type: :submit do %>
    <%= Spree.t(:add_items_to_cart) %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I ended up going with was adding a hidden field with the id of the product. Then I bound a JS event handler to the form so when it's submitted, I prevent the default action and create an array of the product IDs for which the checkbox was selected. Then I iterate over that array and send a POST request to the Spree API at the url `/api/v1/orders/${orderNumber}/line_items?line_item[variant_id]=${itemID}&line_item[quantity]=1`, and redirect them to the cart page.